# Can we Convert the List Items into ListNames?

Tags: python, list

I have two Lists,

```
lst_names = ['lst_0', 'lst_7', 'lst_3', 'lst_7', 'lst_4', 'lst_7', 'lst_5', 'lst_7', 'lst_8', 'lst_0']
// containing the list names

lst_items = [1780, 967, 1613, 657, 1714, 897, 1575, 507, 208, 1910] 
// containing list items
```

What I wanna do is to fetch the 1st element from lst_items and put it into lst_0, 2nd item into lst_7, and so on.... BTW I've created the lists from lst_0 to lst_9

Here is the code that I've been working on,

```
lst_1 = [random.randrange(1000) for i in range(10)]

lst_2 = [random.randrange(1000) for i in range(10)]

def some_func(x, y):

    lst1 = x
    lst2 = y
    l_lst = len(lst1)
    
    lst_add = []
    for i in range(l_lst):
        lst_add.append(lst1[i] + lst2[i])
        
    lst_mod = []
    for i in range(l_lst):
        lst_mod.append(lst_add[i] % 10)
        
    lsts = []
    for i in range(l_lst):
        lsts.append('lst_{}'.format(lst_mod[i]))
        
    g = globals()
    for llst in set(lst_mod):
        g['lst_{}'.format(llst)] = []
        
    print(lsts)
    print(lst_add)

some_func(lst_1, lst_2)
```

I'm new to `Python`, can somebody please guide me through this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having several individual variables like `list_0` through `list_9`, it is probably better having either a list of lists, or a dictionary of lists. You can then `zip` the two lists together and add the elements to the respective list.

```
lst_names = ['lst_0', 'lst_7', 'lst_3', 'lst_7', 'lst_4', 'lst_7', 'lst_5', 'lst_7', 'lst_8', 'lst_0']
lst_items = [1780, 967, 1613, 657, 1714, 897, 1575, 507, 208, 1910]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for n, i in zip(lst_names, lst_items):
    d[n].append(i)
```

Afterwards, `d` is the following:

```
{'lst_0': [1780, 1910],
 'lst_7': [967, 657, 897, 507],
 'lst_3': [1613],
 'lst_4': [1714],
 'lst_5': [1575],
 'lst_8': [208]}
```